# Laravel route Subdomain RegEx

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am having trouble getting regex working in my subdomain routing.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Current Code:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '(one|two|three).example.com'), function()
{
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Enhanced Router extension](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) for  `Laravel 4` router to provide some enhanced functionality :

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{number}.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($number)
    {
        // ...
    });

    Route::get('about', function($number)
    {
        // ...
    });

})->where('number', '(one|two|three)');
```

Comment: this throw the error "Call to a member function where() on a non-object"

Comment: Did you add [Enhanced Router extension](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) to your project using composer ?